# Self join using an additional table in a subquery not selected in the outer select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to Sql, which might explain why I can't figure this out at all.

I have 2 tables from a theoretical social network. One named 'highschooler' and one names 'likes'. 'Highschooler' has info like id(PK), name, and grade whereas 'likes' has id1 and id2 which simply indicate which id's from highschooler have 'liked' each other, with id1 'liking' id2. Likes are not necessarily mutual.

Query: For every student who likes someone 2 or more grades younger than themselves, return that student's name and grade, and the name and grade of the student they like.

This:

```
select h1.name, h1.grade, h2.name, h2.grade
from highschooler h1 inner join highschooler h2 
where h1.id in (select id1 from likes where h1.id=id1 and id1<>id2 and h1.grade>h2.grade+2);
```

is not returning the correct result. In fact the correct result isn't even in the result I get from this query. I'm still trying to wrap my head around "join on" which I feel would be useful here but I don't know how that would work in a self join.

As much as I want to know the answer, more than anything with this I'd just like to know how to do something like this in future because I can't really find any info out there about queries like this as self join examples just demonstrate a singular self join and nothing more complicated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ps This is being run in SQLite

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
select h1.name, h1.grade, h2.name, h2.grade from highschooler h1
join likes l on (h1.id = l.id1)
join highschooler h2 on (l.id2 = h2.id)
where h2.grade <= h1.grade-2
```

Let me know if anything fails :)

Comment: I ended up figuring it out not long after posting but mine is really similar! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query

```
SELECT h1.name, h1.grade, h2.name, h2.grade 
FROM highschooler h1 
  INNER JOIN likes l ON h1.id=l.id1
  INNER JOIN  highschooler h2 ON h2.id=l.id2
WHERE id1 !=id2 AND h1.grade>h2.grade+2
```

Comment: Returns an empty set but I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not 10 damn minutes after posting this I figured it out but screwing around with some inner joins. I've been working on this for like a day: 
    select h1.name, h1.grade, h2.name, h2.grade 
    from highschooler h1
    inner join likes l on h1.id = l.id1 and id1<>id2
    inner join highschooler h2 on h2.id=id2
    where h1.grade >= h2.grade+2